# Modify PrestaShop Home page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop page www.oledia.fr I want to modify the size of the logo, actually when I use web tool through Firefox; I can locate the html code , but i make a search in all the server I cannot find the proper files; and also I go through all the site theme and modules; i cannot find where to modify the size of the picture

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow, you may want to visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some tips on how to perfect your questions that will help us help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Look in your theme file => header.tpl

Else

In your backoffice, theme, upload new logo.

Regards

Comment: thank dear. I use the second option; theme--> Upload new logo and I put the proper size and it's worked

Comment: perfect. I leave you to close the question, and select my answer.

Comment: Side note: If you want to use a transparent background for you logo, you should select "png" as file format in the BO configuration.